# Rails- has_many :through create, delete and access records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below code is from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :physicians do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.timestamps null: false
  end

create_table :patients do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :appointments do |t|
  t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
  t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
  t.datetime :appointment_date
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

end
end

In the above example how do i:

1) Create/destroy a relation between a physician and patient. Do i just use:

```
Create: Appointment.create(physician_id, patient_id)
Destroy: (i have no clue hot to do this)
```

What is the correct way to do it?

2) How would i access all the appointment_date in the Appointment model for a particular patient or physician?

Comment: I am currently creating the relationships using create.  As for the destroy i have been destroying the record on the console. (I am very new to rails sorry if this is really basic)

Comment: I just found the following on another question to create a relationship:@course.topics << Topic.new(params[:topic])

Comment: Your code snippet only assigns a new Topic to a temporary varaible named `@course`. So although the topic is now part of `@course`, and accessible through `@course.topics`, there's no persistent relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an appointment from either the physician or the patient, depending on your preference:

```
@patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
@patient.appointments.create(physician: *object*, appointment_date: *datetime object*)  # auto sets the patient to match the @patient.id

#or from the physician
@physician = Physician.last #select the last physician
@physician.appointments.create(patient: *object*, appointment_date: *datetime object*) # auto sets the physician to match the @physician.id
```

If you have both ID's, you can also create it this way:

```
Appointment.new(patient: *Patient object*, physician: *Physician object*, appointment_date: *datetime object*)
```

To destroy a record, just find the active record object and call destroy on it. Play around in console to see how it works. For instance:

```
Patient.find(id).appointments.last.destroy #destroys the last appointment for a patient with id
```

or find and delete an Appointment directly:

```
# find active record and then call destroy
@appointment = Appointment.find(1) # find appointment with ID: 1
@appointment.destroy

#call destroy directly by chaining commands
Appointment.find(1).destroy #does the exact same thing as above.
```

Comment: Thank you. If i want to destroy a specific relation can i use @Statyx 's method :  @patient.appointments.pluck(:appointment_date) or do you have a different way of doing it?

Comment: pluck is not a method to destroy a record. It fetches a specific field. Look at my last line of code. Just make sure you have the reference to the ActiveRecord you wish to delete and call the destroy method on it. I'll clarify in my answer.

Comment: Perfect! both of you have been a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

1/

```
 Appointment.find_by(physician: @physician, patient: @patient).destroy
```

2/

```
 @patient.appointments.pluck(:appointment_date)
```